# How to programmatically make a folder on Mac OS world-writable?

Tags: macos, cocoa

For my mac os application, I'd like to make a folder it creates (under /Library/Application Support, or maybe somewhere else if that works better) world-writable. Anything else that gets added to that folder would also need to be world-writable. This way multiple users can use the same application without it having to make copies of some large files it uses for each one.

Is there a way to say "Make this folder readable and writable to everyone, and also all items in it, and also all items that will always be created in it" programatically? I don't want to affect just the files in the folder when the command happens - I want to make it affect every file that ever gets created under the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to set your umask to 0 when programmatically writing to the folder and the files inside. 
With a 0 umask, files will be created 666 and directories 777.
See `man -s2 umask`